# Como chamar no Fragment um componente e suas propriedades da Activity?

Tags: java, android, fragment

Precisava que, ao entrar no `Fragment` ele executasse esse método `Verifcar()` na main `Activity` para verificar a condição e não mostrar o `RecyclerView`.

MainActivity.Java

```
public void Verificar(){
            if(pref.getBoolean(Constants.IS_LOGGED_IN,false)){

                recyclerView.setVisibility (View.VISIBLE);
    }else {

                recyclerView.setVisibility (View.INVISIBLE);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode fazer a chamada do método da sua Activity dentro do Fragment usando:

```
((SuaActivity)getActivity()).seuMetodoPublico();
```

Caso tenha problemas com *cast* da Activity, você pode usar:

```
Activity activity = getActivity();

if (activity instanceof SuaActivity){
 ((SuaActivity) activity).seuMetodoPublico();
}
```

Comment: Obrigado pelo pela sua sugestão, porém gostaria que chamasse esse método ao ser chamado o Fragment nesse caso onde eu deveria colocar o método no corpo do Fragment ?

Comment: Recomendo um *override* no método onActivityCreated() do seu Fragment. Assim ele seria chamado somente após a inicialização das Views.

Comment: Rapaz Você é um Gênio, Sucesso e muito obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta serviu pra você, por favor marque ela como a resposta correta para que outros saibam que essa solução serviu. Sucesso pra você também